# Get values from an array / object in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
class MemberView extends Component {
    render() {
        const {users} = this.props;
        console.log('users ', users);
        const currentUserId = this.props.match.params.id;
        const currentUser = users.filter(user => user.id === currentUserId);
        console.log('currentUser', currentUser);
        console.log('currentUserFirstName', currentUser.firstName);
        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        users: state.firestore.ordered.users
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps) (MemberView);
```

I'm trying to figure out why I 'currentUserFirstName' is undefined

[inspect image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ncDj.png)

Comment: Because `currentUser` is an array, try `currentUser[0].firstName` instead

Comment: You might want to enter image description there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filter` method returns an array. While in your case specifically, there should only be one value in that array that passes the condition (that value being the current user), the method will still return an array. That means `currentUser` should actually be equal to `users.filter(user => user.id === currentUserId)[0]`. Try changing that line to:

```js
const currentUser = users.filter(user => user.id === currentUserId)[0];
```